# Any alternatives to VLC transcode for online stream?

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player, streaming, audio-streaming, transcode

I have 2 favorites public radio stations that I always wanted to listen on the phone but due to high quality 192kbps I was not always to listen because it needed good connection. Now using windows VLC command line https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/  I was able to transcode it down to 64kbps and it works perfect on mobile.

Are there any other alternatives on windows? Anything that is maybe web based?
I do also have Ubuntu box.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend Opus as the codec for low bandwidth at good quality. You should be able to find a quality sweet spot that will be on average at maybe even half the 64kbps that you quote.

You can use avconv/ffmpeg for the live transcoding.

As streaming server I personally prefer Icecast. All three have support for sending the encoded stream to it. It's as easy as `sudo apt-get install icecast2` and answering the setup questions. (If it doesn't start by itself double check `/etc/default/icecast2` and the config in `/etc/icecast2/icecast.xml`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 
So I would have to have total of 2 parts to get this work. Icecast and ie. ffmpeg. Icecast would only be there to stream and ffmpeg to convert from high bitrate to something lower? Am I correct?
I need to find command line for audio only because examples from here https://sonnati.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/ffmpeg-%E2%80%93-the-swiss-army-knife-of-internet-streaming-%E2%80%93-part-iv/ are mostly for video.